# Only reading lines that begin with certain prefix

Tags: c#

In my C# program, I'm trying to read in from a txt file only the lines that begin with either Mr., Ms., or Mrs. and then print those lines to a separate txt file but whenever I run what I have, nothing writes to the new file so it is just blank.

Here's what I have:

```
var prefixes = new List<string> { "Mr.", "Mrs.", "Ms." };
var nameIDLines = File.ReadAllLines(filePath)
    .Where(line => prefixes.All(prefix => line.StartsWith(prefix)))
    .ToList();

filteredAsString = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, nameIDLines);

using (StreamWriter outputFile = new StreamWriter(mydocpath + @"\nameIDLines.txt"))
{
    outputFile.Write(filteredAsString);
}
```

Comment: Replace `All` with `Any`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `All` with `Any` as a string can't begin with all of the prefixes, only one of them.

```
var nameIDLines = File.ReadAllLines(filePath)
    .Where(line => prefixes.Any(prefix => line.StartsWith(prefix)))
    .ToList();
```

Comment: oh, okay, I see that now. I'm pretty new to c# so that would explain why I looked that over, makes sense. thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You should use Any:

```
var nameIDLines = File.ReadAllLines(filePath)
    .Where(line => prefixes.Any(prefix => line.StartsWith(prefix)))
    .ToList();
```

Comment: oh, okay, I see that now. I'm pretty new to c# so that would explain why I looked that over, makes sense. thank you!